# How to insert object prop after another prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

So i have this constructor, that will return an object with this props:

```
export function EstateParamsForm() {
  this.estateCategory = createSelectbox('Категория недвижимости', true, () =>
    getEstateOptions('config/estate/categories')
  )
  this.estateType = createSelectbox('Тип недвижимости', true, [])
  this.budgetFrom = createField('input', 'text', 'Бюджет от, руб.')
  this.budgetTo = createField('input', 'text', 'Бюджет до, руб.')
  this.params = []
}
```

In some condition, i want to set prop, for example 'test' after estateType prop. How to do that?

I know, that object props are not ordered, they have 2 rules, if prop name is number, it will order at ASC order, but if it's string, it'll be order as i created in constructor.

May be there is already function in lodash?

Comment: Why you can't just use if for that? `if (/* condition */) this.test = ...;`

Comment: cause i dont want to add it in the constructor. Constructor returns an object, and then in ready object i want to insert new prop in some condition in some order:)